# Getting data from mongoose to frontend using ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongoose

As I m new to node.js and MongoDB, I am getting an error while trying to display the value in the web page like crud.
I want to display the mongoose value to the frontend after user submits the form. I am getting data in console, not on the web page
[image]

Please, anyone, help.Thank you

user_controller.js

```
    const Admin = require('../models/user_model');

    exports.adduser = (req, res, next) => {
        const name =req.body.name;
        const quote = req.body.quote;

        const Admin_save= new Admin();
        Admin_save.name=name;
        Admin_save.quote=quote;
        console.log(Admin_save.name);
        console.log(Admin_save.quote);
        Admin_save.save()
       .then(result =>{
           //console.log(result);
           console.log('Created Admin_panel');
           res.redirect('/firstpage')
       })

    }
```

user_model schema

```
     const adminSchema = new Schema({
           name : 
            {
                type :String
            },
            quote : 
            {
                type: String

            }
        });
```

I want to display using ajax and my ajax file

```
$('submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/data',
        data: $(formid).serialize(),
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){ 
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].name && data[i].quote){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].name+"</td><td>"+data[i].quote+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access mongodb data directly via ajax.
You need to create a new api in nodejs to read the data and then call ajax request on that read api.